# Generating A drop down Grouped List laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a drop down list with products divided by categories, so I can't just use a list like usually I do when I have to list element in a drop down. What I did:

```
$products= DB::table('prod')                
    ->join('cat','cat.id','=','prod.id_cat')
    ->join('campo_cat','campo_cat.id_cat','=','cat.id')
    ->join('campo','campo.id','=','campo_cat.id_campo')
    ->join('cat_nome','cat_nome.id_cat','=','cat.id')
    ->join('lingua','cat_nome.id_lingua','=','lingua.id')
    ->where('lingua.lingua','=','it-IT')        
    ->groupBy('prod.nome')
    ->select('prod.nome as nameprod','cat_nome.nome as namecat','prod.id as id')->get();

$category = [];
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
    if (!isset($category[$product->namecat])) 
    {
        $category[$product->namecat] = [];
    }
    array_push($category[$product->namecat], $product->nameprod);           
}
```

Then I pass it to my view:

```
{{ Form::select('category', array($categorie)) }}
```

Now I can see a drop down, divided by category of my product name, but my key value of array is not the id but it's the standard `0=> 1=>` etc. I want that the values of my drop down select corresponds to the product id. I tried `array_combine()` an array of id with `array_values()` of my array, but it gives error because the name of the category that group each products have `null` values, then it return me array to string conversion error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the new value for the array to the key value of id.

```
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
    if (!isset($category[$product->namecat])) 
    {
        $category[$product->namecat] = [];
    }
    $category[$product->namecat][$product->id] = $product->nameprod;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i didn't know array_push autogenerate key